# linux server pip does not install modules

Tags: python, linux, pip

my `pip -V` returns: `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)`

`python3 -V` returns: `Python 3.6.9`

and when I try installing a module using pip I get the following error:

```
Collecting Django==2.2.1
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/django/`

>Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django==2.2.1 (from versions: )

>No matching distribution found for Django==2.2.1
```

and I read similar questions and I checked that I don't have a proxy set, and my firewall is disabled.

What do I do?

Comment: The only reason you would get a network timeout is a network problem. If it's not a proxy or a firewall then something else in that general direction. Is the network cable plugged?

Comment: @tripleee It's a VPS and te network must be connected bc I installed other stuff and it worked fine, and I can ping sites.

Comment: Can you specifically ping pypi.python.org  ( which resolves to 151.101.4.223 for me) ?

Comment: @ShpielMeister
>PING dualstack.python.map.fastly.net (151.101.12.223) 56(84) bytes of data.
>64 bytes from 151.101.12.223 (151.101.12.223): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=107 ms
>64 bytes from 151.101.12.223 (151.101.12.223): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=107 ms
>64 bytes from 151.101.12.223 (151.101.12.223): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=107 ms
>64 bytes from 151.101.12.223 (151.101.12.223): icmp_seq=4 ttl=50 time=108 ms

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443) with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port)

Answer (score 0):

"`sudo pip install --default-timeout=100 future`"

[How to solve ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443) with pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298872/how-to-solve-readtimeouterror-httpsconnectionpoolhost-pypi-python-org-port)

the sudo may or may not be necessary.  take care when using sudo.

also:  [Issues Installing with Pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53794580/issues-installing-with-pip3)

Comment: Advising blindy to use `sudo pip` may break system Python, please consider editing the advice.

Comment: I'm not advising it.  I'm quoting  an accepted answer with 124 upvotes.  I stated it may or may not be necessary' . i'm editing to be clearer. thx @PierredeBuyl